# Explode Checkbox looping php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, arrays

I want explode data from table "**school_minat**" 
into checklist in checbox looping table from "**dayaminat**".

I already try, but my checklist show only one. whereas my data minat_id in table **school_minat** 4 data = **smk2,smk3,smk1,smk4**

```
<center> 
<?php $sql = "select * from dayaminat";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){  // Looping data from Table "dayaminat"
    ?>
    <input name='minat[]' 
    <?php 
    $values = $result['minat_id']; // Data "minat_id" already Selected in Database table "school_minat"
    $array_of_values = explode(",", $values); //Explode Data "Minat"  already Selected in Database  table "school_minat"
    if (in_array($row['minat_id'],$array_of_values)) {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
    } 
    ?> 
    value='<?php echo $row['minat_id']?>'  type='checkbox'>&nbsp; <?php echo $row['minat'] ?> &nbsp;
    <?php 
    $i ++;
}?>
</center>
```

Help me. Thank's :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must loop in your `$array_of_values`

```
<center> 
<?php $sql = "select * from dayaminat";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){  // Looping data from Table "dayaminat"
    $values = $result['minat_id']; // Data "minat_id" already Selected in Database table "school_minat"
    $array_of_values = explode(",", $values); //Explode Data "Minat"  already Selected in Database  table "school_minat"

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_values); $i++) {
    echo "<input name='minat[]' ";
    if (in_array($row['minat_id'], $array_of_values)) {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
    } 
    ?> 
    value='<?php echo $array_of_values[$i]; ?>'  type='checkbox'>&nbsp; <?php echo $array_of_values[$i]; ?> &nbsp;
    <?php 
  }
}?>
</center>
```

Comment: i try 
type in outside while

i type

$values = $result['minat_id'];
$array_of_values = explode(",", $values); 
echo $values; // My data show smk2,smk3,smk1,smk4

i try type again
echo $array_of_values;  // only show text "Array"

Comment: if you want see $array_of_values you must do this print_r($array_of_values);

Comment: i try it, is array show.
but why my checklist always not show :(

Answer (score 1):

You are looping only through the database row. As there is just 1 row you get only 1 result.

So try looping through the array! Probably using foreach loop..

```
<center> 
<?php $sql = "select * from dayaminat";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){  // Looping data from Table "dayaminat"

    $values = $result['minat_id']; // Data "Minat" already Selected in Database table "school_minat"
    $array_of_values = explode(",", $values); //Explode Data "Minat"  already Selected in Database  table "school_minat"?>
    foreach ($array_of_values as $arrayItem){

        <input name='minat<?php echo $i;?>' 
        <?php 

        if (in_array($row['minat_id'],$arrayItem)) {
        echo 'checked="checked"';
        } 
        ?> 
        value='<?php echo $arrayItem ?>'  type='checkbox'>&nbsp; <?php echo $arrayItem ?> &nbsp;
        <?php 
        $i ++;
    }
}?>
</center>
```